# Linq to XML Remove multiple returns

Tags: c#, linq

Hi have a Linq Query to extract some information. Following is the part of it.

```
 node = "DocumentClass";
 AVariable="Something"
 na="NA";
 var documentClassesScript = (from documentClass in configparentXML.Descendants(node)
                              where documentClass.Attribute("Name").Value.Contains(AVariable)
                              select new ReadingXmlWithLinq
                                       {
                                        CustomStorageString = documentClass.Element("ValidationPluginAssociations") != null ? documentClass.Descendants("ValidationPluginAssociation").Attributes("CustomStorageString").Single().Value : na,
                                        } 
  ).Distinct();
```

In Some case i got following error

> Sequence contains more than one
>   element

The reason is `ValidationPluginAssociations` contain more than one `ValidationPluginAssociation`. I need to distinct and get only one of them. Is there any way to get it.

Comment: That exception usually comes from using `Single()` on a sequence that contains more than one element (hint hint).  You need to verify that the sequence will produce a single element or use a different method.

Comment: Maybe you need `FirstorDefault`

Comment: Thank you very much. I got your point. I fixed it by using First() :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is no need to have single object you can use First:

```
documentClass.Descendants("ValidationPluginAssociation")
             .Attributes("CustomStorageString").First().Value
```

Comment: I think `FirstOrDefault()` would be better if it can.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins, I think it's better catching exceptions instead of skip them, later bad problems can be happens.

Comment: how?with `try-catches`?what about performance issue?`First()` generally gives `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error that is why if you are not sure about the result you should use `FirstOrDefault()` so it can will prevent the error.And I think we can never be sure.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins - in the code above, the Value is immediately accessed causing a NullReferenceException when using FirstOrDefault.  Calling First is better in this style, as it provides a better exception message.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins, I think what david said is enough but one more thing when using first, if there is no such element throws: `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements` so you can understand what happens, but by first or default you get: `object reference not set to an instance of an object` so First is better than first or default (at least you can understand possible locations, every piece of code can throw null reference) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx exceptions part

Comment: what if I don't want to catch the exception? @David B @Saeed

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins, Also I don't like to cach exceptions (in cash block I'll throw more reasonable exception), but I try to throw valuable exception, if you don't like to throw valuable exception, you should spend too many time to resolve your coding problems or ur customer mis understandings (except you and your customer are GOD and there isn't any mistake in ur jobs).

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins - you can catch the exception or not at your discretion.  That's not the choice we're talking about.  We're talking about using First vs using FirstOrDefault.  In the above code - BOTH will throw.  First will throw SequenceContainsNoElements.  FirstOrDefault().Value will throw NullReference.  That's your choice.